# Basic proxy still processing web browser requests even after program has been terminated?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, proxy

So I'm in a networking class at university, and the first part of the assignment is to write a proxy that a browser can simply connect to, be appended with `/<url>`, and then the proxy will return the web page content for the browser to display.

Because it's a class, I don't want to post all of my code, (But I'll gladly post some of it if requested).

My question is this: I create a socket on the proxy to listen for a connection through:

```
   browser_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
   browser_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 10000)) #listen on local host with arbitrary port number.
   browser_socket.listen(1)
```

After accepting a browser connection to: `127.0.0.1:10000/google.com`, the proxy will serve google's web page to the browser (client). I'm pretty sure this is working as it's supposed to because before I run the program, if I try to type in `127.0.0.1:10000/google.com`, it won't serve the web page, and when running the program, navigating to: `127.0.0.1:10000/google.com` does serve the web page.

Here's my question: after I terminate the application (close the command line AND delete the running python executable from windows task manager), **I can now always connect to** `127.0.0.1:10000/< url >`, and it works! Even after restarting my computer, I can still access web pages this way!

I'm very curious as to why this is happening. If I test it by changing the port number, like:
`127.0.0.1:18890/google.com`, it won't connect. But then if I run the proxy A **single time** with the port to 18890 like so:

```
browser_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 18890)) #listen on local host with arbitrary port number
```

It displays the same behavior, and If I restart the computer, I can now connect with `127.0.0.1:10000/< url >`, *and* with `127.0.0.1:18890/< url >`!

It's a mystery to me. I would love to learn and be enlightened by this, does anyone have an answer? Would using a try: finally, or ensuring I close the port at the end of the program change the behavior?

If so, why would this continue running even after restarting my computer?

Comment: I would guess that this is browser caching - either the browser is caching the lookup of its own accord, or a http redirect is being encountered somewhere along the way?

Do you get the same behaviour if after terminating the proxy you connect to the address using a different browser or application?

Comment: You may be right, since I've been only testing this out on chrome. When I just tried it out on Edge, I couldn't connect through the sockets I had ran the proxy on previously, while I still could access the proxy through those ports on chrome. Also, while navigating to the correct port on edge, I noticed I can connect when running the proxy but not when the proxy is terminated. Is there anywhere I can read up on how chrome caches these kinds of things, or any other sources I can look into to try and figure this out?